# USACO Runtime error: Illegal file open (/dev/tty)

Tags: c, runtime-error

I'm solving a problem on USACO and the grader gives me the following error:

> Run 1: Execution error: Your program had this runtime error:
>           Illegal file open (/dev/tty). The program ran for 0.003 CPU
>           seconds before the error. It used 2164 KB of memory.

According to the USACO help page, the error is related with out-of-bound array indexing. I succeed tested my code with several test cases and I've been careful about bounds and array indexing but unfortunatelly I can't find the error. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i, flag, flag2, lcount, rcount, gcount, nbeads, start;
    char right, left, necklace[800];

    FILE *fin  = fopen ("beads.in", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen ("beads.out", "w");

    fscanf(fin, "%d %s", &nbeads, necklace);
    strcat(necklace,necklace);
    necklace[2*nbeads] = '\0';

    flag = 1;
    left = right = ' ';
    start = gcount = 0;

    // First cut
    for(i = start, lcount = 0; necklace[i] != right && i < nbeads; i++, lcount++)
        if((flag) && (necklace[i] != 'w')){
            left = necklace[i];
            right = (left == 'b') ? 'r' : 'b';
            flag--;
        }           

    gcount = lcount;
    if(i < nbeads){
        // Remaining cuts
        flag = 2;
        flag2 = 0;

        for(start = i; start > 0 && necklace[start - 1] == 'w'; start--, lcount--);
        while(flag){                            
            for(i = start, rcount = 0; necklace[i] != left && i < 2*nbeads; i++, rcount++);
            gcount = (gcount < lcount + rcount) ? lcount + rcount : gcount;
            lcount = rcount;
            right = (right == 'b') ? 'r' : 'b';
            left = (left == 'b') ? 'r' : 'b';
            for(start = i; start > 0 && necklace[start - 1] == 'w'; start--, lcount--);                     
            if(!flag2 && start >= nbeads){
                gcount -= (i - nbeads);
                break;
            }
            flag2++;
            if(start >= nbeads) flag--;         
        }
    }

    fprintf(fout, "%d", gcount);

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `strcat(necklace,necklace);` is suspicious and causes a crash in Visual Studio.  All of the documentation I have seen states the behavior is undefined if the strings overlap.

Comment: Yeah! That was the error. Thank you so much!